# Converting a single retrieved sql value to string in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel, I want to convert SQL result to string in laravel, below is what I did even though I dont get the result a desire, that is returning client_name as a string.

```
$client_name = DB::table('utility_data')
    ->select('client_name')
    ->where('identity_number', '=', $identity_number)
    ->first();

dd($client_name);
```

Above script select client name from the database, I want to convert that value to a string, any idea on how to achieve this? This is what I get as result,
I want to extract the value "Nosi Chefane":

```
{#303 ▼
  +"client_name": "Nosi Chefane"
}
```

Comment: `->get()` and `->first()` don't work together, use `->first()` only

Comment: I am getting this as result: "{#303 ▼
  +"client_name": "Nosi Chefane"
}" any idea how to get the value "Nosi Chefane"

Comment: `$client_name->client_name`?

Comment: yes I want it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you printing it from a controller, just use `return $client_name` and you should see the data as a JSON object

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to return just the name itself, you'd have to access it within the object returned in the query:

```
dd($client_name->client_name);
```